# getting error :Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/flutter_launcher_icons - Not found in npm install

Tags: node.js, node-modules

when i try to install node modules, `npm install` i am getting this error

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://registry.npmjs.org/flutter_launcher_icons - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'flutter_launcher_icons@^0.7.4' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'latus-react-pwa-app'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
```

can anyone please help me why i am getting this error ?, can anyone please help me is there anything i am missing there ?

Comment: because in npm, this library not exists

Comment: thanks i removed it from packages